# How to open local file in Js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display an image that is stored locally on my disk. I have tried this:

```
     image.src = "file:/Users/user/Desktop/photo.png";
```

But I get the following error: "Not Allowed to Load Local Resources".
I use Google Chrome on Mac.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. JavaScript is not allowed to access the file system. If you are working without a server, just make the path relative to the location of the .html file, not relative to C:\

Comment: You are not able to open files from a local drive through JavaScript when loading the HTML container file from an HTTP server. Try uploading your image to an external server to serve them trough HTTP.

Comment: Launch the Google Chrome browser from the command line window with the additional argument '–allow-file-access-from-files'.